# Integrating FullPage.js as a Wordpress Plugin: Can I adjust this plugin to work along side other plugins?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, fullpage.js

I recently followed [this post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-apple-inspired-full-page-scrolling-pages-for-your-wordpress-site/) on integrating FullPage.js as a WordPress plugin.

I'm having trouble getting the plugin to work with other plugins - such as "All in one Event Calendar". The calendar works it just won't display on pages using FullPage.js

I understand the limitations that a plugin meant for landing pages has, but I was wondering if there was any way to edit the existing FP plugin template so that it can utilize other plugins while also taking over the theme's template?

Perhaps editing this statement?:

```
function fullpage_template( $original_template ) {

  if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'fullpage_js', true ) ) {
  return dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/fullpage.php';
  } else {
  return $original_template;
  }

}
```

I really appreciate any assistance on this!

Comment: In case you are interested, there's a good wordpress theme using fullpage.js [here](https://goo.gl/HuFudq).

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problems because you are using `verticalCentred:true` or `scrollOverflow:true`.

As said in [the fullpage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions)

> **My other plugins don't work when using fullPage.js**
>
> **Short answer:** initialize them in the afterRender callback of fullPage.js.
>
> **Explanation:** if you are using options such as verticalCentered:true or overflowScroll:true of fullPage.js, your content will be wrapped inside other elements changing its position in the DOM structure of the site. This way, your content would be consider as "dynamically added content" and most plugins need the content to be originally on the site to perform their tasks. **Using the afterRender callback to initialize your plugins, fullPage.js makes sure to initialize them only when fullPage.js has stopped changing the DOM structure of the site.**

Comment: Hi Alvaro,  

Is there anything else I need to add to the afterRender callback? I read through your documentation and tried using the afterRender callback but the calendar plugin still doesn't load on pages in the FullPage.js template.

`afterRender: function(){
            var pluginContainer = $(this);
            alert("The resulting DOM structure is ready");
        }`

Comment: You need to initialize your other plugins there.